# How to start windows program from WSL Ubuntu Xterm in foreground (on top of all other programs)?

Tags: cygwin, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use git and invoke `git difftool` command from Xterm (that Xterm "runs" WSL shell). My difftool command is set up to start p4merge Windows application.

Everything works alright, but p4merge's window is displayed under all currently visible windows. Specifically, under the Xterm window that started it.

This drives me a bit nuts because if I need to diff 20 files, then I need to Alt+Tab 20 times manually.

I've just migrated from Cygwin to WSL and this exact setup started p4merge on top of all other windows in Cygwin.

So, how do I make WSL start a program and make sure that its window is topmost?